# How to define a common interface/type definition for functions with overlapping parameters?

Tags: typescript, types

I have **multiple** functions with overlapping params. For example, take two functions as

```
fn1({p1, p2}: {p1: string, p2: string})()
fn2({p2, p3}: {p2: string, p3: string})()
```

To reduce duplication, I have been using following two methods, but none of them are ideal

```
Method 1
type Params = {
  p1?: string,
  p2?: string,
  p3?: string
}

fn1({p1, p2}: Params)
fn1({p2, p3}: Params)
```

Issue with this method is it allows calling the function without the required parameters

```
Method 2
type Params = {
  p1: string,
  p2: string,
  p3: string
}
fn1({p1, p2}: Omit<Params, 'p3'>)
fn1({p2, p3}: Omit<Params, 'p1'>)
```

Issue with this method is it shows parameters which are not in focus for the function.

Is there a better method to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I've made `Args` type that allows simply pick optionable properties for using as function arguments.

```
interface AllArgs {
  num: number,
  str: string,
  null: null,
}

type Pure<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] }
type ReplaceEnd<S, L extends string> = S extends `${infer F}${L}` ? F : S
type Args<K extends keyof AllArgs | `${keyof AllArgs}?`, Extend extends Record<any, any> = {}> =
  | Pure<
    & Pick<AllArgs, K & keyof AllArgs>
    & Partial<Pick<AllArgs, ReplaceEnd<K, '?'> & keyof AllArgs>>
    & Extend
  >;

type y = Args<'num' | 'str?', { foo: true }>
//   ^?
// type y = { num: number; str?: string; foo: true; }

function f({ num, foo, str }: Args<'num' | 'str?', { foo: 'bar' }>) {
  console.log(num)
  //          ^?
  // (parameter) num: number
  console.log(str)
  //          ^?
  // (parameter) str: string | undefined
  console.log(foo)
  //          ^?
  // (parameter) foo: "bar"
}
```

(If there is a betted way please @ me, I also use this concept)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I took AllArgs as the first argument in the generic and moved it to util, so that I can use it at many places